# How do I push selected checkboxes into an array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having trouble getting the checkboxes in my rows to work.

All my checkboxes are showing up as selected and I am getting the following error `Error in v-on handler:"referenceError: networkAudience is not defined`
How do I fix this error? or is there a better way to push selected checkboxes into an array?

```js
data()
{
networkAudiences: {},
selected: []
},
methods:
{
 selectedNetAudience()
  {
  this.selected = [];
  for (networkAudience in this.networkAudiences)
  
  this.selected.push(this.networkAudiences[networkAudience].id);          
  }
}
```

```html
<tr
v-for="(networkAudience) in fixedNetworkAudiences(audience)"
:key="audience.id + networkAudience.id"
 >    
  <td>
   <input
     class="form-check-input"
     type="checkbox"
     autocomplete="off"
     :checked="selected"
     @change="selectedNetAudience()">
  </td> 
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the array.push should inside the for loop open the curly bracket put them inside

Comment: Have you tried logging the this.networkAudiences[networkAudience] before pushing it's id into this.selected? 
Seems that such item does not exist.